# How to get video download link from Google Drive in PHP?

Tags: php, video, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get the download source from a Google Drive file I own. I currently have this code:

```
$videoSRC = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/". $_GET['id']. "?alt=media&key=API_KEY_HERE";
echo '<video autoplay="" preload="auto" src="'. $videoSRC. '"></video>';
```

The problem is, when you look at the video source, it says the video source is "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/GOOGLE_FILE_ID?alt=media&key=API_KEY_HERE". While it does display the video, I've seen that website have their video source as "https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback". How are they able to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the webContentLink of the file which is generated by using the [Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get#request).

Files.get uses the following URI request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId
```

Tried this on one of my file and got this webContentLink:

```
https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0Bzgk4zccNwI7MmJOYWs3SG1VUUE&export=download
```

You can pass this link in your GET request in PHP and see if it downloads the file.

Comment: That does work, although the files have to be below 25mb, or else they are promoted with a "Google can't scan this file for viruses" message.

Comment: I think using [Partial Download with Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#partial_download) is what you need for that task.

Comment: But using Partial Download would only display a specific portion of the video, I would like to be able to display the entire video.